# Cadence throwing WorkflowRejectedExecutionError when executing workflow with many child workflows/activities

Tags: java, kotlin, cadence-workflow

I am evaluating the use of Cadence for performing long-running bulk actions. I have the following (Kotlin) code:

```
class UpdateNameBulkWorkflowImpl : UpdateNameBulkWorkflow {

    private val changeNamePromises = mutableListOf<Promise<ChangeNameResult>>()

    override fun updateNames(newName: String, entityIds: Collection<String>) {
        entityIds.forEach { entityId ->
            val childWorkflow = Workflow.newChildWorkflowStub(
                    UpdateNameBulkWorkflow.UpdateNameSingleWorkflow::class.java
            )
            val promise = Async.function(childWorkflow::setName, newName, entityId)

            changeNamePromises.add(promise)
        }

        val allDone = Promise.allOf(changeNamePromises)
        allDone.get()
    }

    class UpdateNameSingleWorkflowImpl : UpdateNameBulkWorkflow.UpdateNameSingleWorkflow {
        override fun setName(newName: String, entityId: String): SetNameResult {
            return Async.function(activities::setName, newName, entityId).get()
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine for smaller numbers of entities, but I quickly run into the following exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure processing decision task. WorkflowID=b5327d20-6ea6-4aba-b863-2165cb21e038, RunID=c85e2278-e483-4c81-8def-f0cc0bd309fd
    at com.uber.cadence.internal.worker.WorkflowWorker$TaskHandlerImpl.wrapFailure(WorkflowWorker.java:283) ~[cadence-client-2.7.4.jar:na]
    at com.uber.cadence.internal.worker.WorkflowWorker$TaskHandlerImpl.wrapFailure(WorkflowWorker.java:229) ~[cadence-client-2.7.4.jar:na]
    at com.uber.cadence.internal.worker.PollTaskExecutor.lambda$process$0(PollTaskExecutor.java:76) ~[cadence-client-2.7.4.jar:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
Caused by: com.uber.cadence.internal.sync.WorkflowRejectedExecutionError: java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task java.util.concurrent.FutureTask@7f17a605[Not completed, task = java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter@7fa9f240[Wrapped task = com.uber.cadence.internal.sync.WorkflowThreadImpl$RunnableWrapper@1a27000b]] rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@22188bd0[Running, pool size = 600, active threads = 600, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 2400]
    at com.uber.cadence.internal.sync.WorkflowThreadImpl.start(WorkflowThreadImpl.java:281) ~[cadence-client-2.7.4.jar:na]
    at com.uber.cadence.internal.sync.AsyncInternal.execute(AsyncInternal.java:300) ~[cadence-client-2.7.4.jar:na]
    at com.uber.cadence.internal.sync.AsyncInternal.function(AsyncInternal.java:111) ~[cadence-client-2.7.4.jar:na]
...
```

It appears that I am quickly exhausting the thread pool and Cadence is unable to schedule new tasks.

I have worked around this by changing the definition of `updateNames` to:

```
    override fun updateNames(newName: String, entityIds: Collection<String>) {

        entityIds.chunked(200).forEach { sublist ->
            val promises = sublist.map { entityId ->
                val childWorkflow = Workflow.newChildWorkflowStub(
                        UpdateNameBulkWorkflow.UpdateNameSingleWorkflow::class.java
                )
                Async.function(childWorkflow::setName, newName, entityId)
            }

            val allDone = Promise.allOf(promises)
            allDone.get()
        }
    }
```

This basically processes the items in chunks of 200, and waits for each chunk to complete before moving onto the next one. I have concerns with how well this will perform (a single error in a chunk will stop processing of all records in the following chunks while it is retried). I'm also concerned with how well Cadence will be able to recover the progress of this function in the event of a crash.

My question is: Is there an idiomatic Cadence way of doing this that doesn't cause this immediate resource exhaustion? Am I using the wrong technology or is this just a naive approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cadence workflow has relatively small limit on the size of a single workflow run. It scales out with the number of parallel workflow runs. So executing very large number of tasks in a single workflow is an anti-pattern.

The idiomatic solutions are:

- Run a chank of limited size and then call continue as new. This way a single run size is bounded.
- Use hierarchical workflows. A single parent with 1k children each executing 1k activities allows executing 1 million activities keeping each workflow history size bounded.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response Maxim! When you say "executing very large number of tasks in a single workflow is an anti-pattern", does "task" in this context mean both child workflows and activities? 
In the first example I gave the parent doesn't directly start any activities, but it does wait for many child workflows to complete, so in my testing I have one parent workflow with 5000 child workflows, and each of the children has 1 activity. This is what causes the resource exhaustion.

Comment: I believe it should work with 5k children. Would you file an issue against https://github.com/temporalio/java-sdk/issues? Anyway I would recommend "continue as new" approach as it would scale to any number of children.